# Reporting services expression for default value

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report, default-value

the following error is displayed when deploy reports,
"**The Value expression for the report parameter ‘Year’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected** "

The problem is in default value expression for parameter Year.

```
=Switch(
CInt(System.DateTime.Now.Month) >3,
    Year(Today()),
CInt(System.DateTime.Now.Month) <=3,
    {Year(Today.AddYears(-1)),Year(Today())}

)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can just rewrite the above as:

```
=IIf(Month(Today) > 3, Year(Today), Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Today)))
```

i.e. If Today is in April to December, use the current year, else use the previous year.

Comment: The condition is OK, but in else statement I need previous year and current year.